# Transform a column of lists in a column of values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list

I'm trying to split a column and make some verifications. My objective is return 9 boolean columns in a dataframe, but te actual result is 9 columns of lists.

```
d = {'Posicao': ['MO (DC), PL (C)', 'GR, PL (C)', 'MO (DEC), PL (C)']}
dfF = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

```
def definir_pos(x):
    GR = []
    AT = []

    GR_t = 0
    AT_t = 0
    
    splited = x.split(',')

    for splite in splited:    
        
        if 'GR' in splite:
            GR_t = 1

       
        if 'PL' in splite:
            AT_t = 1

    GR.append(GR_t)
    AT.append(AT_t)
    
    dataf = [GR,AT]
    
    return dataf
```

```
posicoes = dfF.Posicao.apply(definir_pos)
posicoesF = pd.DataFrame(posicoes.tolist(), columns = ['GR','AT'])
```

I just put 2 option in def, but in original code has 9

Output:

```
    GR  AT
0   [0] [1]
1   [1] [1]
2   [0] [1]
```

Expected output:

```
    GR  AT
0   0   1
1   1   1
2   0   1
```

Comment: Can you please give the expected output for some input ?

Comment: Done. Added expected output

Comment: @LorantRomano please accept as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In case you were not aware of some of the pandas methods, I have refined your code a lot, and it returns desired output. *This code is much simpler and will have significantly better performance*. You can use `str.split()` method with `expand=True`. Then use `str.contains()` to search for 'GR' and 'PL' simultaneously in each column by separating the two strings with an "or" operator `|`:

```
d = {'Posicao': ['MO (DC), PL (C)', 'GR, PL (C)', 'MO (DEC), PL (C)']}
dfF = pd.DataFrame(d)

dfF = dfF['Posicao'].str.split(',',expand=True).rename({0:'GR',1:'AT'}, axis=1)
dfF['GR'] = dfF['GR'].str.contains('GR|PL').astype(int)
dfF['AT'] = dfF['AT'].str.contains('GR|PL').astype(int)
dfF
Out[1]: 
   GR  AT
0   0   1
1   1   1
2   0   1
```

If you want this to be function, it still can be with:

```
def definir_pos(df):
    cols = ['GR', 'AT']
    df = df['Posicao'].str.split(',',expand=True).rename({0:'GR',1:'AT'}, axis=1)
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].str.contains('GR|PL').astype(int)
    return df


definir_pos(dfF)
```

Or, you can include a `cols` parameter:

```
def definir_pos(df , cols):
    df = df['Posicao'].str.split(',',expand=True).rename({0:'GR',1:'AT'}, axis=1)
    for col in cols:
        df[col] = df[col].str.contains('GR|PL').astype(int)
    return df


definir_pos(dfF, cols=['GR', 'AT'])
```

Comment: note the assignment `dfF[['GR', 'AT']] ` isn't actually needed. Provided you don't mangle the index, you can just return a separate series/df so the drop isn't needed later

Comment: @anon01 yes, that is one way, but then you would need an extra step to rename the columns right? So, you subtract one step but you would add another? I do agree that the approach is slightly better though, because it would be more performant, as renaming two column values is probably speedier and definitely more memory efficient than having an extra column that is later dropped.

Comment: Yeah, totally fine either way - I just prefer not making intermediate/temporary mutations of the dataframe